# Android notification type API

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

Wanted to get notification type but I am not able to get it. I took reference from : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/category-element.html

Manifest setting :

```
<service android:name="com.edgealert.NotificationMonitor" android:label="EdgeAlert"android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" ></action></intent-filter> </service>
```

Code :

```
package com.edgealert;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService;
import android.service.notification.StatusBarNotification;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;

public class NotificationMonitor extends NotificationListenerService {

    StatusBarNotification[] actNot;

    @Override
    public void onListenerHintsChanged(int hints) {

    }

    public void notificationProcess(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        Consts.listItemList = new ArrayList<ListItem>();

        Log.d("fff", "Icon tray reset");
        Bundle extras;
        HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> Alerts = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
        ListItem listItem = new ListItem();
        actNot = getActiveNotifications();

        NotificationDataObject.lastNotification = sbn.getPackageName();
        Intent intent = null;
        synchronized (actNot) {
            //actNot = sortNotificationbyTime(actNot);  
        }

        Log.d("fff", "Size=======" + actNot.length);
        Consts.listItemList = new ArrayList<ListItem>();

        for (int i = 0; i < actNot.length; i++) {
            Log.d("fff","when ="+new Date(actNot[i].getNotification().when) + actNot[i].getPackageName());  
            extras = actNot[i].getNotification().extras;
            intent = new Intent(MainActivity.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
            intent.putExtra("appName", actNot[i].getPackageName());
            try{
            listItem = new ListItem();
            listItem.app_ic = getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(actNot[i].getPackageName());
            listItem.appName = actNot[i].getPackageName();
            if(!isIconExist(listItem)){
                Log.d("fff", "Icon tray add new icon "+listItem.appName);
                Consts.listItemList.add(listItem);
            }
            else
                Log.d("fff","tray icon "+ listItem.appName +" appears twice");

            }
            catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("fff","error in adding app icon");
            }
            ArrayList<String> tempArray;
            /*
             * if (Alerts.containsKey(actNot[i].getPackageName())) tempArray =
             * Alerts.get(actNot[i].getPackageName()); else
             */
            tempArray = new ArrayList<String>();

            try {
                Log.d("fff", "appName" + actNot[i].getPackageName());
                String ndo = getNotificationData(extras, actNot[i].getPackageName());
                Log.d("fff", "ndo string" + ndo);
                tempArray.add(ndo);
                Alerts.put(actNot[i].getPackageName(), tempArray);

            } catch (NullPointerException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("fff", "NullPinter ====== in notification process" + e);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            intent.putExtra("EdgeAlert", Alerts);

            sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, null, new MyReceiver(), null, Activity.RESULT_OK, null, null);
        }

    }

    public String getNotificationData(Bundle extras, String appName) {

        JSONObject ndo = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray messageTextLines = new JSONArray();
        JSONArray jr = new JSONArray();
        CharSequence[] lines = extras.getCharSequenceArray(Notification.EXTRA_TEXT_LINES);
        try {

            messageTextLines = doIt(lines);
            if (messageTextLines == null)
                messageTextLines = new JSONArray(); 
            ndo.put("appName", appName);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("fff", "in get notification data");
        }
        String from = "";
        String msg = "";
        boolean messageTextAlreadyparsed = false;
        // messageTextLines = parseMessages(messageTextLines);
        CharSequence titleBigText = extras.getCharSequence(Notification.EXTRA_TITLE_BIG);
        CharSequence titleText = extras.getCharSequence(Notification.EXTRA_TITLE);
        CharSequence infoText = extras.getCharSequence(Notification.EXTRA_INFO_TEXT);
        CharSequence subText = extras.getCharSequence(Notification.EXTRA_SUB_TEXT);
        CharSequence summaryText = extras.getCharSequence(Notification.EXTRA_SUMMARY_TEXT);
        CharSequence messageBigText = extras.getCharSequence(Notification.EXTRA_BIG_TEXT);
        CharSequence messageText = extras.getCharSequence(Notification.EXTRA_TEXT);
        Log.d("fff", appName);
        Log.d("zzz", "__________________________");
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(titleText))
            Log.d("zzz", "titleText....." + titleText);
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(titleBigText))
            Log.d("zzz", "titleBigText....." + titleBigText);
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(infoText))
            Log.d("zzz", "infoText....." + infoText);
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(subText))
            Log.d("zzz", "subText....." + subText);
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(summaryText))
            Log.d("zzz", "summaryText....." + summaryText);
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(messageBigText))
            Log.d("zzz", "messageBigText....." + messageBigText);
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(messageText))
            Log.d("zzz", "messageText....." + messageText);
        Log.d("zzz", "before text lines " + appName);
        if (messageTextLines != null)
            Log.d("zzz", "message Extra Text....." + messageTextLines.toString());
        Log.d("zzz", "after text lines " + appName);
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(titleText)) {
            from = titleText.toString();
            Log.d("zzz", from);
            jr.put(from);
        } else if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(titleBigText)) {
            from = titleBigText.toString();
            Log.d("zzz", from);
            jr.put(from);
        } else if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(messageText)) {
            from = messageText.toString();
            Log.d("zzz", from);
            jr.put(from);
        }
        Log.d("fff", "before text lines 2nd " + appName);
        if (messageTextLines != null) {
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(messageBigText)) {
                messageTextLines.put(messageBigText.toString());
            } else if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(messageText)) {
                if (messageText.toString().contains("\n")) {
                    String splited[] = messageText.toString().split("\n");
                    for (int i = 0; i < splited.length; i++) {
                        Log.d("fff", "i = " + i + "   " + splited[i]);
                        messageTextLines.put(splited[i]);
                    }
                } else
                    messageTextLines.put(messageText.toString());
            }
            Log.d("fff", "after text lines 2nd " + appName);
        }

        try {
            switch (appName) {
            /*
             * case "com.google.android.gm": ndo.put("from", jr);
             * ndo.put("msgs", messageTextLines); break; case "com.whatsapp":
             * 
             * ndo.put("from", jr); ndo.put("msgs", messageTextLines);
             * 
             * break; case "com.facebook.orca":
             * 
             * ndo.put("from",jr); ndo.put("msgs", messageTextLines ); break;
             * 
             * case "com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.mail":
             * 
             * ndo.put("from", jr); ndo.put("msgs", messageTextLines); break;
             * 
             * case "com.skype.raider": if(messageTextLines.length()==1){ from =
             * titleText.toString(); msg = messageText.toString(); }
             * ndo.put("from", from); ndo.put("msgs", msg); break;
             * 
             * case "com.google.android.talk":
             * 
             * ndo.put("from", jr); ndo.put("msgs", messageTextLines); break;
             */

            default:
                ndo.put("from", jr);
                ndo.put("msgs", messageTextLines);
                break;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("fff", "json probolem");
        }
        Log.d("fff", "get notification data " + ndo.toString());
        return ndo.toString();
    }

    private JSONArray doIt(@Nullable CharSequence[] lines) throws Exception {
        JSONArray j = new JSONArray();
        if (lines != null) {
            // Filter empty lines.
            JSONArray s = new JSONArray();
            for (CharSequence msg : lines) {
                msg = removeSpaces(msg);
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(msg)) {
                    s.put(msg.toString());
                }
            }

            // Create new array.
            if (s.length() > 0) {
                return s;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static String removeSpaces(@Nullable CharSequence cs) {
        if (cs == null)
            return null;
        String string = cs instanceof String ? (String) cs : cs.toString();
        return string.replaceAll("(\\s+$|^\\s+)", "").replaceAll("\n+", "\n");
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        {

            Log.d("fff", "icon tray reset");
            //Consts.listItemList = new ArrayList<ListItem>();
            notificationProcess(sbn);
        }
    }
    public boolean isIconExist(ListItem li){
        boolean isExist = false;
        ArrayList<ListItem> lis = Consts.listItemList;
        for(ListItem cli : lis){
            if(cli.appName.equals(li.appName))
                isExist = true;
        }
        return isExist;
    }
    @Override
    public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {

        Log.d("fff", "removed notification " + sbn.getPackageName());
        notificationProcess(sbn);
    }

    public StatusBarNotification[] sortNotificationbyTime(StatusBarNotification[] sbns){
        ArrayList<StatusBarNotification> sNotification = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(sbns));
        Collections.sort(sNotification, new Comparator<StatusBarNotification>() {
              public int compare(StatusBarNotification o2, StatusBarNotification o1) {
                  return new Long(o1.getNotification().when).compareTo(o2.getNotification().when);
              }
            });

        return sNotification.toArray(new StatusBarNotification[sNotification.size()]);
        //return sbns;
    }

}
```

Please let me know if I am missing any thing
Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by `get notification type`?

Comment: How to know that notification is from sports app, social app or mail app... something like this. -@bjiang